# Firefox will not play this html piece but Chrome and Opera will any hint?

Tags: html, firefox, audio, wav

The following code snippet works perfect in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox
Any hint on what may be the problem?.

```
<audio autoplay><source src="/lyd/CAMERA.wav" type= "audio/wave"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct, firefox still does not supports 12, 20, 24, 32 bit files only . Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, do you have a pointer to a utility which can tell me about the bit level of my wav files, I have many of them? Running windows xp